# Reply Mail Management - can one sender profile have reply option and the other one not?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

when having 2 Sender profiles -> is it possible to set RMM in a way that Transactional/Operational emails will have the option to "REPLY" with active RMM and it will be forwarded to routing email address as usual when the Commercial emails won't be enabled for the reply option at all?

If yes, how is the set-up done within Email/Admin section?

Thank you
Lea

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with [Custom Reply Mail Management settings on the Sender Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_sender_profile_for_use_with_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null).

**Email Studio>Administration>Sender Profile**